# Can a out-of-process COM object find out which process has loaded it?

Tags: c#, .net, com, localserver

I have an out-of-process COM server (LocalServer) that serves several objects and I don't know ahead of time which process will activate my served classes. The activation will be via the IDispatch interface so everything is late-bound.

When one of the served classes is constructed, I would like to be able to identify the activating process somehow, perhaps get the name of the executable so that I can display it in the COM LocalServer.

For a .NET developer all this COM chicanery can be a bit dizzying, so I'd appreciate it if someone can suggest how I might determine how (by whom) my served classes are being activated.

Comment: Offhand I don't know a way...doesn't mean there isn't a way.  If you are the developer of both the client and the server, you can obviously add a method to your server so that the client can pass the process ID.

Comment: No.  This has a very simple solution, just let the client tell you.